# MySQL not working when running PHP script from Chef Recipe in Vagrant

Tags: php, mysql, virtual-machine, chef-infra, vagrant

I've got a custom virtual machine base box that has PHP, Apache2 and MySQL pre-installed. So I can just boot up the virtual machine using this box and it wont need to install any of the above from Chef Cookbooks.

However, there is one Chef Cookbook I'm trying to install, but it's failing. The Cookbook I'm trying to install runs a PHP script, which connects and uses a MySQL db.

The reason it fails is because PHP cannot connect to the mysql server. I think it's because MySQL isn't started (or ready) at the time the script tries to connect. It only fails when I boot the VM. When I provision it (vagrant provision), it works. So that's why I think MySQL isn't ready to go when the PHP script attempts to connect.

The errors:

> mysql_connect(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) in .....

And the code in the Chef Cookbook Recipe:

```
execute "doInstall" do
  cwd "/vagrant"
  command "php path/to/my/script.php"
end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I've had this problem and discussed it here: github.com/xforty/vagrant-drupal/issues/11. I don't have an answer, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can do a

```
service "mysql" do
  action :start, :immediately
end
```

at the beginning of your recipe or simply do a heuristical

```
execute "doInstall" do
  cwd "/vagrant"
  command "sleep 10; php path/to/my/script.php"
end
```

which seems a bit dirty to me but might solve your issue quickly.

Comment: This seemed to work, but, only on the second attempt (of booting the VM). So I first boot it, and it still fails. But when I shut it down and boot it again, it seems to work, but then, if I shut it down again, and boot it up, it fails...It's failing and working in a pattern.

Comment: I've also tried sleeping it for 10-20 seconds, but the same thing happens.

Comment: Hmm, may be MySQL related than - the service is running but does not accept connections for some strange reason

Comment: I was wrong, It doesn't fail in a pattern, just when it wants to. It works most times, but fails sometimes, too.